# Why am I receiving an error when trying to create the database by the URL of "jdbc:h2:test"

Tags: java, database, directory, h2

I am trying to create a database with the URL of "jdbc:h2:test:, as stated on H2's web site ([here](http://www.h2database.com/html/faq.html#database_files)) under "Where are the Database Files Stored?". It states "If the base directory is not set (as in jdbc:h2:test), the database files are stored in the directory where the application is started (the current working directory).", which is exactly what I would like.

I am receiving the error "A file path that is implicitly relative to the current working directory is not allowed in the database URL "jdbc:h2:test". Use an absolute path, ~/name, ./name, or the baseDir setting instead. [90011-182] 90011/90011".

What does this error mean? And why can't I create a database with the URL that H2's web site tells me to use?

Thank you in advance for any helpful answers.

Regards,

Ryan Shukis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is in the [H2 Error documentation](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/api/ErrorCode.html#c90011). It's a good practice - especially when dealing with RDBMS, which tend to have cryptic errors, to look up the error number in their manuals.

In essence, this is not allowed by default, to prevent confusion. You can set a system option to disable checking this, or you could use an explicitly relative path (`./test`).

Comment: What does "`./test`" do? If you are referring to creating an absolute path, this would not be beneficial for me. I need the database stored in a location that can be accessed via a shared location, and I need the application to know what that location is without having to prompt for input from the user every time the application is run.

Comment: It is an **explicitly relative** path, as I (and the documentation) said. The "." is a convention borrowed from Unix which means "current directory". So it means *current_directory*/test

Comment: Okay, gotcha. So, that would store the database in the same directory as the Java files, correct?

Comment: The current working directory is (usually) the directory where the process was started. So it depends on how you start the process (you can use `java -cp ...` to start it from any directory).

Comment: @Ryan - No, actually. And neither will using "jdbc:h2:test" do that. The current working directory is the directory your user was in when the `java` command was called.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying the `jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/test` URL instead and making the path an explicit path to your application folder. (As shown at the end of the same paragraph that your current URL came from).

Its complaining about relative paths not being viable, so give it an absolute path instead.

Comment: As I have stated in another comment, creating an absolute path would not be beneficial for me. I need the database stored in a location that can be accessed via a shared location, and I need the application to know what that location is without having to prompt for input from the user every time the application is run.

Comment: Why does the "C:" have to be there? Can't "/data/test" translate to "C:/data/test" like every other java app in existence?  This is fundamental core library features.  It makes mixed computer development environments messy.